# How to migrate from docker-compose to vagrant?

Tags: mysql, docker, phpmyadmin, vagrant

Here is my docker-compose file that works fine and I want to reproduce the same results using Vagrant:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.36
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test_db
    ports:
      - "3308:3306"
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      PMA_USER: root
      PMA_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
```

Execute `docker-compose up` and visit localhost:8080 `phpmyadmin` works fine.
When I try to the same with `vagrant` containers are built and they are running, but `phpmyadmin` is unable to communicate with `mysql` container.
Here is my `Vagrantfile`:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.define "mysql" do |db|
        db.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3306, host: 3308
        db.vm.hostname = "mysqldb"
        db.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
          d.image = "mysql:5.7.36"
          d.env = {
            :MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD  => "root",
            :MYSQL_DATBASE        => "test_db"
          }
          d.remains_running = "true"
        end
      end
    config.vm.define "phpmyadmin" do |pa|
        pa.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
        pa.vm.hostname = "phpmyadmin"
        pa.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
            d.image = "phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest"
            d.env = {
                :PMA_HOST       => "mysqldb",
                :PMA_USER       => "root",
                :PMA_PASSWORD   => "root"
            }
            d.remains_running = "true"
        end
    end
end
```

How can I get the `phpmyadmin` and `MySQL` working together with `vagrant`?

Comment: Do you need to separately [configure networking](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/providers/docker/networking)?  Compose automatically creates a Docker network between the containers, but it's not obvious whether Vagrant does or not.

Comment: All want is `phpmyadmin` accessing the `MySQL` db. I just want to reproduce what `docker-compose` does.

Comment: If you connect through the console to your phpMyAdmin instance, are you able to correctly resolve and pass network traffic to the MySQL machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. I need to define the network at the top level.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# This file works exactly like the docker-compose.yml file.
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    # Define the network, using which the containers can communicate
    config.vm.network :private_network, type: "dhcp"
    config.vm.define "mysql" do |db|
        # Without prot forwardign vagrant entwork doesnt work
        db.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3306, host: 3306
        db.vm.hostname = "mysqldb"
        db.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
          d.image = "mysql:5.7.36"
          d.env = {
            :MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD  => "root",
            :MYSQL_DATBASE        => "test_db"
          }
          d.remains_running = "true"
        end
      end
    config.vm.define "phpmyadmin" do |pa|
        pa.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
        pa.vm.hostname = "phpmyadmin"
        pa.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
            d.image = "phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest"
            d.env = {
                :PMA_HOST       => "mysqldb",
                :PMA_USER       => "root",
                :PMA_PASSWORD   => "root",
                # Without specifying the specific port phpadmin container doesn't work
                :PMA_PORT       => "3306", 
            }
            d.remains_running = "true"
        end
    end
end
```

<s>I still need to solve one more problem - how to define a dependency between vms. Build the VM `phpmyadmin` only after `mysql` is up and running.</s>

Unlike `docker-compose` it is not possible to set a direct dependency in `vagrant`. But it is possible to do a sequential build by setting the option `--no-parallel` eg:- `vagrant up --no-parallel`.

Even though `docker-compose` has the dependency set, the dependency is only to the extent of waiting for the dependent container to be built but not waiting for the services in the container to be up and running.

Hence even after building sequentially in `vagrant`, the dependent services failed to connect. It did not matter `vagrant` or `docker-compose`. Services with in the containers need to wait for their dependent services to be up.

So I added a delay in the dependent containers in a timed loop, the dependent service will attempt to connect and upon failure will wait for 30 seconds to connect again, after 10 attempts it gives up.